# Nuget Error Microsoft.Bcl.Build while installing Microsoft.Net.Http in Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, nuget, nuget-package

I have a project in Xamarin Forms and I want to consume service from an external page. I am trying to install the package *Microsoft.Net.Http* to consume such services and gives me the following error:

Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14'. You are trying to install this package in a project that has 'MonoAndroid, Version = v6.0' as the destination, but the package does not contain assembly references or content files that support that framework. For more information, contact the author of the package. 0]

Comment: try System.Net.Http instead

Answer (score 0):

In the error message there must be specified the Target Framework Version which is in conflict with Xamarin.Forms v6.0
If you have a "packages.config" file in your Droid project, look for this line inside:

```
<package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.4.0.280" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
```

And replace *"monoandroid60"* with the proper one. I had this trouble installing Microsoft.Net.Http and I could resolve with it. Just try...

On the other hand, if you can try with System.Net.Http package, last version is only some days ago.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same or similar issue and solved it by manually installing the *Microsoft.Bcl* nuget package before installing the *Microsoft.Net.Http* package.

It might also help to update the Xamarin nuget packages.

(Idea from Workaround mentioned here: [Source](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43070))